# Python assignment index error

Tags: python, indexing

```
def main():
    rows = int(input("Insert # of rows "))
    cols = int(input("Insert # of cols "))
    dept = int(input("Insert # of dept ")) 
    count = 0
    trash = count


    table = [[[ 0
        for i in range(cols) ]
             for j in range(rows) ]
                  for k in range (dept) ]
    print ()
    print ("Print empty table")
    print(table)
    print()

    print("Print each element")

    for i in range(rows):
        print("-" * 30, "rows", i+1)
        for j in range(cols):
            print("-" * 22, "col", j+1)
            for k in range (dept):        
                count += 1
                table [i][j][k] = count 
                print ("row", i+1, "column", j+1, "depth", k+1, "=", count)

    print()
    print(table)
main()
```

This works fine if all 3 numbers are the same. If they aren't, it stops the first time one of the variables has to go above it's designated number. ie. If 2, 3, and 2 are entered, it will work fine until it reaches the 3rd column and then stop, giving this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/prog123", line 28, in main
    table [i][j][k] = count
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

If I take out the line:

```
table [i][j][k] = count
```

It works fine, except it doesn't fill in the table. It also works fine if I make it only have two dimensions(taking out depth). Moving the line to earlier or later in the code doesn't seems to help either. I looked through similar questions on here already, but didn't see anything that helped me catch the error here.

Comment: I think the table definition is wrong, it should be `[ [ [ range(dept) ] -- range(cols) ] -- range(rows) ]` instead of `[ [ [ cols ] -- rows ] -- dept ]`, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was some simple(stupid) error on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table = [[[ 0
    for i in range(cols) ]
         for j in range(rows) ]
              for k in range (dept) ]
```

This will make your *innermost* list (the one indexed *last*, i.e. with `k`) have `cols` elements.  That's not what you meant, even with `cols` and `rows` switched around.

Nested list comprehensions work from the inside out, so you want this written backwards from how you loop over it:

```
table = [[[ 0
    for k in range(dept) ]
         for j in range(cols) ]
              for i in range(rows) ]
```

Then the rest of your code should work unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized I could do that, and had forgotten to check back on this. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You have your indices mixed up.

You built the table with `dept` outer lists, with the very inner lists having `cols` elements. You then try to address the innermost elements with a loop over `range(dept)` and the outermost list with `range(rows)`.

Python list comprehensions should be read from left to right as if they are nested; you even formatted your list comprehension that way:

```
table = [[[ 0
    for i in range(cols) ]
         for j in range(rows) ]
              for k in range (dept) ]
```

But your second nested `range()` loops and indices don't match that structure; replicate it when assigning. Move the `depts` range loop out and adjust how you use `k` to reference cells:

```
for k in range(dept):        
    for i in range(rows):
        print("-" * 30, "rows", i+1)
        for j in range(cols):
            print("-" * 22, "col", j+1)
                count += 1
                table[k][i][j] = count 
                print("depth", k+1, "row", i+1, "column", j+1, "=", count)
```

Note how now the nesting matches; `k` (`dept`), then `i` (`rows`), then `j` (`cols`).